# Create warnings in R

Tags: r, warnings

I wanna write a script whicht makes R usable for "everybody" at this special topic of analysis. Is there a possibility to create warnings?

```
time,value
2012-01-01,5
2012-01-02,0
2012-01-03,0
2012-01-04,0
2012-01-05,3
```

For example if the value is at least 3 times 0 (afterwards - better within a settet period of time - 3 days) give warnings - and naming the date. Maybe create something like a report, if I am combining conditions.

In general: Masurement data are read via read.csv and then set Date by as.POSIXct - xts/zoo. I want the "user" to get a clear message if the values are changing etc.; if they are 0 for a long time etc. 
The second step would be sending emails - maybe running on a server later.

Additional Questions:
I do have a df in xts now - is it possible to check if the value is greater a threshold value? It's not working because it's not an atomic vector.

Thanks

Comment: additional question: is it possible to create a pop up? or sent message by mail?

Comment: There is a 'sendmailR' package.

Comment: Can you explain what you're tying to do with this? Who is using this script, and where would you want messages to go? Where does the data come from?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this.

```
x <- read.table(text = "time,value
2012-01-01,5
2012-01-02,0
2012-01-03,0
2012-01-04,0
2012-01-05,3", header = TRUE, sep = ",")

if(any(rle(x$value)$lengths >= 3)) warning("I noticed some dates have value 0 at least three times.")

Warning message:
I noticed some dates have value 0 at least three times.
```

I'll leave it to you as a training exercise to `paste` a warning message that would also give you the date(s).

Comment: Thanks - this does check if there are ANY values in x more than three times. Maybe there is also a chance to get the date or at least the line of error - if the data are much more huge this would be very helpful.

Comment: @HerrStudent of course,`rle` gives you all the information you need to infer position/date.